# Can I make an ipywidget floatslider with a list of values?

Tags: python, jupyter, ipywidgets

I would like to make an ipywidget floatslider, but passing it a list of values, rather than a range and step.  Is there a way to do this, or is making a dropdown widget the only option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Woops!  You can use SelectionSlider, e.g.:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

def test(val):
    print(val)

widgets.interact(test, val=widgets.SelectionSlider(description='value',   options=['1', '50', '300', '7000']))
```

This widget wasn't available in my ipywidgets 4.0, so I had to upgrade.  Also, make sure that afterward you run

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension
```

as described in their installation instructions.